# Copy entities from one Breeze EntityManager to another EntityManager

Tags: breeze

This [breeze documentation page](http://breeze.github.io/doc-cool-breezes/multiple-entitymanagers.html) has this sample for making a copy of an EntityManager:

```
function createManager() {
   // same configuration; no entities in cache.
   var manager = masterManager.createEmptyCopy(); 

   // ... copy in some entities (e.g.,picklists) from masterManager

   return manager;
}
```

I am not sure how I am supposed to do the "`copy in some entities (e.g.,picklists) from masterManager`" step.

I guess I could just go create the entities as if they are new.  But they are not, they are picklist values that were queried from the database.

I thought about trying to use Export/Import, but that seems like it is intended for offline work and serializes all the values to string.  (Which seems like it may not be as performant as what I would like.)

**Is there "normal" way that everyone copies entities between EntityManagers?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you copy the entities by exporting and importing.  For performance, you should specify

- `asString: false`, to avoid string serialization overhead, and
- `includeMetadata: false`, since `createEmptyCopy()` creates an `EntityManager` that already has metadata

So:

```
function createManager() {
   // same configuration; no entities in cache.
   var manager = masterManager.createEmptyCopy(); 

   var entities = masterManager.exportEntities(null, { asString: false, includeMetadata: false });
   manager.importEntities(entities);

   return manager;
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  For further reference, I found a breeze doc that discusses this (right as you answered!):  http://breeze.github.io/doc-cool-breezes/import-save-results.html